# Generate getters and setters using UltiSnip in Vim

Tags: java, python, vim, getter-setter, ultisnips

I want to create an UltiSnip code in which is similar to the one used in their [Github README](http://i.imgur.com/AC75jNE.gifv).

I understand it involves python interpolation and I am finding it difficult to write my own interpretation. Their [documenation](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt) gives a good list what UltiSnip can do, yet it still difficult to get what I am trying to do.

I want to automatically generate public methods to get and set instance variables, such as I type in this...

```
class Foo()
{
     int x;
     double y;
     ...
```

and UltiSnip should add this portion...

```
     public void setX(int _x)
     {
          this.x = _x;
     }

     public int getX()
     {
          return this.x;
     }

     public void setY(double _y)
     {
          this.y = _y;
     }

     public double getY()
     {
          return this.y;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[lh-refactor](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor) provides the generate getter/setter refactoring methods for Java and a few other languages.

Naming conventions can be tuned independently of the snippets used internally.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what UltiSnips (and other snippets plugins) are about. You can indeed easily write `setter` and `getter` snippets that expand to the corresponding function, with placeholders for the attribute name and type. But defining *all* getters and setters for a class just from what's currently defined is stretching this functionality too much; you'd need a (rudimentary) language parser, and might want to implement attribute additions / attribute type or name changes, too.

I know that most IDEs provide such functionality out of the box, but they are special-purpose tools for a very limited set of programming languages, not a general-purpose text editor like Vim. If you really love this functionality, just use an IDE of your choice in paralled to editing the same source code file with Vim. Or use the mentioned simpler snippets and accept a bit more typing from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have problems with posting here the code with the symbol `
then I used github:  github.com/robertbnd/notes/blob/master/stack

only you need to write "int x" and press the key you selected in your snippets
My case is :  let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="`"
you can personalize it

Answer (score 0):

Use eclim for this. Just select the attributes with visual mode and then :JavaGetSet :)